# I keep getting an error saying "cannot convert from int to Drawable". I'm trying to assign an image to places. Is there a way of working around this?

Tags: java, android, overlay, drawable

I can't seem to reference my image in the drawable folder. I have the image there however i keep getting an error stating that I cannot convert an int to Drawable. my R.java generated file has the string in there for the image however it is set as "public static final int restaurant=0x7f020001;"

```
package com.CS3040.Places;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.CS3040.*;
import com.CS3040.Coursework.R;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlaceOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {
    private final GeoPoint point;
    private final Place place;
    private final Drawable marker;

    public PlaceOverlayItem(Place p, String type) {
        super(p.getGeoPoint(), p.getName(), p.getFormatted_address());


        if(type.equals("restaurant")){ this.marker = R.drawable.restaurant;  }

        //super.setMarker(this.marker);
        this.point = p.getGeoPoint();
        this.place = p;
    }

    /**
     * @return the point
     */
    public GeoPoint getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    /**
     * @return the place
     */
    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to do as follows:

```
marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);
```

The reason you get the message "The method getResources() is undefined for the type PlaceOverlayItem" is because getResources() is a method inherited from Context class, so you got to call it from an Activity (or so) or pass the context to your method.

Hope this helps

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated as of today.

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated now, use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22

Answer (score 7):

I think you want something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.restaurant);
this.marker = bitmap;
```

Or, using your solution:

```
marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);
```

Comment: Good answer! Remember to `recycle()` your bitmaps when you're finished with them.

Comment: Thanks guys for you help, I'm still getting an error with the getResources. "The method getResources() is undefined for the type PlaceOverlayItem".

Comment: getResources() is a method on Activity.

Comment: the `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);` is deprecated and you might have to use something like `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.restaurant)`

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.restaurant` is a constant int which holds the id of the drawable resource **resturant**, it is not a Drawable object.

Comment: Hey it kinda worked but now it says "The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type PlaceOverlayItem".

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin version**

To convert the drawable into the Bitmap, just use this block of code

```
val largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.my_large_icon)
```