# Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-5.1.1-lollipop

With new android API 22 `getResources().getDrawable()` is now deprecated.
Now the best approach is to use only `getDrawable()`.

What changed?

Comment: Could you specify your question? It is right that the method `getDrawable (int id)` of the class `Resources` is deprecated. You should now use the method `getDrawable (int id, Resources.Theme theme)` with the new theme parameter.

Comment: ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.color.color_name)

Comment: You can check out [**my blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html) on this subject for a more thorough explanation about why both `Resources#getDrawable(int)` and `Resources#getColor(int)` were deprecated.

Comment: Google should put quick-fixes for each deprecated function.  I made a post about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219495

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

You have some options to handle this deprecation the right (and **future proof**) way, depending on which kind of drawable you are loading:

---

**A)** drawables *with* theme attributes

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
```

You'll obtain a styled Drawable as your Activity theme instructs.
This is probably what you need.

---

**B)** drawables *without* theme attributes

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);
```

You'll get your unstyled drawable the old way. Please note: `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` is **not** deprecated!

---

**EXTRA)** drawables *with* theme attributes from *another* theme

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, anotherTheme);
```

Comment: My app crashes using suggestion B. It doesn't like the call Drawable originalIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ctxt.getResources(), iconResId, null);

Comment: I declare it this way:     public static void setImageButtonEnabled(Context ctxt, boolean enabled,
                                             ImageButton item, int iconResId) {

        item.setEnabled(enabled);
        Drawable originalIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ctxt.getResources(), iconResId, null);
        Drawable icon = enabled ? originalIcon : convertDrawableToGrayScale(originalIcon);
        item.setImageDrawable(icon);
    }
and call it like this:         Utility.setImageButtonEnabled(getContext(), false, back, R.drawable.arrow_left);

Comment: More precisely, the crash seems to be happening because my icon is a Vector drawable.

Comment: xamarin version: ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.name, null);

Comment: I add one further word to you，ContextCompat.getColor(context,color) also can help you...

Comment: Using this in an adapter like this - ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(viewGroup.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.touch_feedback, null);

Comment: Do deprecated it and replaced it with something worse. I'm not calling getResources every time someone clicks on a button. That's woeful.

Answer (score 759):

#### Edit: see [my blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html) on the subject for a more complete explanation

---

You should use the following code from the support library instead:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```

Using this method is equivalent to calling:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

As of API 21, you should use the `getDrawable(int, Theme)` method instead of `getDrawable(int)`, as it allows you to fetch a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID for the given screen density/theme. Calling the deprecated `getDrawable(int)` method is equivalent to calling `getDrawable(int, null)`.

Comment: I think that the OP also refers to the `getDrawable (int id)` method of the `Context` class. This is the same as `getResources().getDrawable(id, getTheme());` and also uses the new API.

Comment: According to documentation, min API level 21 is required to use `getDrawable(int, Resources.Theme)`.

Comment: @Prince The method was added in API 21 but it wasn't deprecated until API 22. :)

Comment: Android doc also recommends using [Context::getDrawable(int) method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)) but since it was introduced only in API 21 seems that ContextCompat is the best choice.

Comment: This answer does not work with .svg files, in versions older than API 21. There is a bug in the library.

Comment: The suggestion fails when called from a Fragment:         Drawable originalIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.arrow_left);

Answer (score 150):

Replace this line :
    `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable)`

with `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable, null)`

EDIT

`ResourcesCompat` is also deprecated now. But you can use this:

`ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable)` (Here `this` is the context)

for more details follow this link: [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)

Comment: Thats depricated now too:https://plus.google.com/+BenjaminWeiss/posts/M1dYFaobyBM

Comment: see this link please : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context, int)

Comment: It doesn't say in [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html) that `ResourcesCompat` is deprecated. It should work fine.

Comment: what to write in "your drawable" if i want to input images to a list view on clicking list items stored in drawable

Answer (score 29):

#### [`getResources().getDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)) was deprecated in API level 22. Now we must add the theme:

[getDrawable (int id, Resources.Theme theme)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))  (Added in API level 21)

This is an example:

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

This is an example how to validate for later versions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //>= API 21
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
   } else { 
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
}
```

Comment: `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP is API 21`, so shouldn't this be `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)` or `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`? Never mind. From below "The method was added in API 21 but it wasn't deprecated until API 22. :)"

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.drawable_resource_name);
```

Answer (score 10):

**getDrawable(int drawable)** is deprecated in API level 22.
For reference see this *[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))*.

Now to resolve this problem we have to pass a new constructer along  with id like as :-

```
getDrawable(int id, Resources.Theme theme)
```

For Solutions Do like this:-

**In Java:-**

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
```

**or**

```
 imgProfile.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_prof, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

**In Kotlin :-**

```
rel_week.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.color.colorWhite)
 or,
rel_week.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.color.colorWhite)
)
```

**or**

```
 rel_day.background=resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home, context?.theme)
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that getDrawable(DrawableRes int id, Theme theme)  can throw an exception if the resource is not found while, getDrawable(Context context, int id) is nullable, so it has to be returned with Drawable? in Kotlin.

Comment: This formatting is utterly horrible and the code in Kotlin do not compile

Comment: @J.Doe yes , this may be old code . I will update the new answer.

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin you can use extension

```
fun Context.getMyDrawable(id : Int) : Drawable?{

    return  ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, id)
}
```

then  use like

```
context.getMyDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.example);
```

that's work for me

Comment: Using application context to load vector drawable crashes on pre lollipop. Any fix for this?

Comment: @muthuraj I don't remember my testing for the code with lollipop case, but you can try getActivity() or getResources() instead then, does that goes well with your code ?

Comment: I'm using MVVM pattern and I need to inflate drawables inside ViewModels which don't have activity context. It only has application context. That's what my issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of how I fixed the problem in an array to load a listView, hope it helps.

```
 mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
//    Resources resources = getResources();

//    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.az_lgo), getString(R.string.st_az), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
//    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ca_lgo), getString(R.string.st_ca), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
//    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.co_lgo), getString(R.string.st_co), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.az_lgo, null), getString(R.string.st_az), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ca_lgo, null), getString(R.string.st_ca), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.co_lgo, null), getString(R.string.st_co), getString(R.string.all_nums)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static List<ProductActivity> getCatalog(Resources res){
    if(catalog == null) {
        catalog.add(new Product("Dead or Alive", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.product_salmon),
                "Dead or Alive by Tom Clancy with Grant Blackwood", 29.99));
        catalog.add(new Product("Switch", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.switchbook),
                "Switch by Chip Heath and Dan Heath", 24.99));
        catalog.add(new Product("Watchmen", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.watchmen),
                "Watchmen by Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons", 14.99));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting SDK > 21 (lollipop or 5.0) use

```
context.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_name)
```

[See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int))

Answer (score 0):

en api level 14

```
marker.setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.miubicacion, null));
```

Comment: You should provide a bit more context around your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to implement like this

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //>= API 21
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
```

Following single line of code is enough, everything will take care by ContextCompat.getDrawable

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some who still got this issue to solve even after applying the suggestion of this thread(i used to be one like that) add this line on your Application class, onCreate() method

`AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`

As suggested [here](https://medium.com/@david.debre/my-experience-with-vector-drawables-some-tips-79ff2fbad68b) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean)) sometimes this is required to access vectors from resources especially when you're dealing with menu items, etc

Answer (score 0):

In case you need drawable from other app targeting SDK 23 and up

```
PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
Resources resources = null;
try {
    resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication("com.anyapp");
    } 
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
assert resources != null;
Drawable notiIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, current.iconId/* drawable resource id */, null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP should now be changed to BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop
i.e:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) {
    this.Control.Background = this.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.AddBorder, Context.Theme);
} else {
    this.Control.Background = this.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.AddBorder);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `BuildVersionCodes` a class specific to Xamarin?