# Android deprecated methods

Tags: java, android

I try to add two methods for getDrawable(), because this method is deprecated.
What's wrong?

```
    public class Misc {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int resource) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource, null);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int resource) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
    }

}



Duplicate method getDrawable(Context, int) in type Misc line 11 Java Problem
Duplicate method getDrawable(Context, int) in type Misc line 16 Java Problem
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following code from the support library instead:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```

Using this method is equivalent to calling:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
   {
     return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme()); 
   } 
 else 
  {
    return resources.getDrawable(id); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two methods with the same signature (same method name, same parameters, etc.).

Rewrite it as:

```
public class Misc {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int resource) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource, null);
        }

        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
    }

}
```

Comment: I get The method getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated by the second return

Answer (score 0):

The error is you used `overload` incorrectly! Specifically, it is not allow to have 2+ methods have the same name with same input params.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined it twice.

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int resource) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource, null);
    }
}
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: context.getResources().getDrawable(resource, null); is showing that Call requires API level 21. I have to use minSDK 19. I cant set it to 21 in my app.