# Android get system icon programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Java (not XML) to add system drawable to a layout and I am able to do this in xml part but can't figured out how do I add system drawable in java ?

in Xml

```
android:Drawable="@android:drawable/cursor"
```

how to program in java

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable img = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.cursor);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just do it

```
Drawable img = res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.cursor);
```

For API 22 and above have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/1306012

Comment: Method deprecated.Please provide alternate

Comment: @blackjack have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/1306012

Answer (score 0):

In your code, replace `R.drawable.cursor` with `android.R.drawable.cursor`.

For API 22 and above:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.cursor)
```