# ImageView src and background

Tags: android, imageview

How to change the imageview's src as well as background programatically not in xml?

setBackgroundResource() : same behaviour as setBackground().

But in xml, we got the option to set the src as well as background.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use setBackgroundResource() to set background and setImageBitmap() for setting source.

Comment: i think you need to R&D and then need to ask question. you have tried any thing??

Comment: @PankajAndroid you should try this: (1) setBackgroundColor()    (2) setBackgroundResource    (3) chnage setBackgroundResource()                          You will understand the difference.

Comment: i had tried and achieve but this type of question are already ask.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code

For Src:

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

For Background:

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `setImageResource()` method:

```
.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.imageID, null));
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)