# Android: How to set in XML File drawable

Tags: android, xml

My XML File test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="img_test" type="imgt" drawable="testimage"></item> 
</resources>
```

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

My aim:

In the onCreate() Method, set to in xml file on drawable ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clear your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you meant, but you could use this method to get your Drawable:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.img_test);
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29041466/4230150) for more information.