# How replace getDrawable

Tags: android, android-widget, android-drawable

getDrawable is depreceated. How can I rewrite this code. I am unable to find the  answer.

```
   public static List<Product> getCatalog(Resources res){
    if(catalog == null) {
        catalog = new Vector<Product>();
        catalog.add(new Product("Dead or Alive",src.getDrawable(R.drawable.deadoralive),
                "Dead or Alive by Tom Clancy with Grant Blackwood", 29.99));
        catalog.add(new Product("Switch", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.switchbook),
                "Switch by Chip Heath and Dan Heath", 24.99));
        catalog.add(new Product("Watchmen", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.watchmen),
                "Watchmen by Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons", 14.99));
    }

    return catalog;
}
```

What is the new best way to use it funcation.

Comment: Its a duplicate question

Comment: I know a lot of question had been asked about geDrawable on this site But I am new to  Android Development so I needed exact answer as I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

using [ContextCompat.getDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)). E.g.

```
  Drawable drawable = ContextCompat(context, R.drawable.deadoralive);
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22), you must use

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```