# Xamarin Android SetBackgroundDrawable deprecated but not SetBackground()

Tags: android, xamarin, android-drawable

```
var textView = parentView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_chat_message);
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.SetCornerRadius(10);
gd.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
textView.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

As in the example above `SetBackgroundDrawable` allows me to control the color and radius programmatically. I have looked at `SetBackgroundResouce` but I cannot find a clear example as it just seems to take an ID to a resource that I could not change progamatically.

Could someone help me providing an alternative that gives me the flexibility to do the exact same as `SetBackgroundDrawable` above please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [Background](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Background/) property.  Generally whenever Android has a getX/setX method with no arguments, Xamarin converts it to a C# style property named X.

```
var textView = parentView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_chat_message);
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.SetCornerRadius(10);
gd.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
textView.Background = gd;
```

Comment: But I cannot change the radius using `Background` alone (unless I am being dumb, which is entirely possible : )

Comment: Background is still a Drawable, so you should be able to use the same approach as before.  See my edit

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a Xamarin thing but your edit blows up, It's a little late in the day now so I will try and debug tomorrow and find the reason why, thanks for help. much appreciated.

Comment: This is the error I am receiving in the output when trying to do as you have suggested `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setBackground' signature='(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V' in class Landroid/view/View;`

Comment: My emulator was running on 3.1 needs to be 4.12 or higher for this to work, many thanks. For reference see this report https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26624

Comment: for anyone else I used a check for version like so `BuildVersionCodes sdk = Build.VERSION.SdkInt;
                        if (sdk < BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
                        {
                            TextView.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           TextView.Background = gd;
                        }`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `SetBackgroundDrawable(back);` use `Background = back;`

You have to do like this:

```
back = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.cover);
// SetBackgroundDrawable(back);
Background = back;`
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Based on running it on device it seems `Background` property is not completely implemented at the moment (11.11.2015). My trial and error approach points out that setting `Background` through the property is throwing exception that it didn't find the `setBackground` method with appropriate arguments. So the issue is not with the new way of getting the drawables but when you try to set them. Maybe I'm misusing this so I'm open for corrections.

```
//Works
yesButton.SetBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.selector_green_button));

//Works
yesButton.SetBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.selector_green_button, Resources.NewTheme()));

//Doesn't Work     
yesButton.Background = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.selector_green_button, Resources.NewTheme());

//Doesn't Work
yesButton.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.selector_green_button);

//Doesn't Work
yesButton.Background = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.selector_green_button);
```

**Original Answer**

You can use the Background property as @Jason Suggested already.

In order to use that you'll need to get the Drawable now the funny part:

`GetDrawable` method is deprecated (since API 22 i think) so you should be using :

```
someControl.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.your_drawable);
```

instead of `Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.your_drawable);`

Found this link for reference: [More info on getting drawables in Android native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure this plays well with Xamarin, I will also look further into this tomorrow, thanks also for your suggestion and link.

Comment: I just ran it on the emulator before I post but not tested on device, will do tomorrow at work (it requires `using Android.Support.V4.Content`) but VS will let you know :)