# Sent a Image from drawable to a ImageView?

Tags: javascript, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGSYR.png)I'm working in a project called gift card, which is a simple app. When a user is in an activity, they can click in a photo and when they click, it will appear as background of another activity. I'm trying to solve this but nothing is working. Can you help me but please in a simple way because im a beginner in Android Studio.
Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getDrawable(id) is deprecated since API 22. Now you need to specify Theme.

```
 getResources().getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
```

In order to support previous android versions use the following:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```

[Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Comment: Use "this" instead of "context"

Comment: but in fact maybe have no sence because i can do all this codin in activity 2 you understand what im saying because in activity 2 the client can click in the photo and when they click ,the background with change of activity one the data can i sent with intent but image i dont know how to do that because im and new in android

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a drawable on an ImageView as in the below code:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

Comment: It works in mine, although my app's target SDK is API 23.

Comment: i dont know why but anyways thank you now i have solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(
            "imagename", "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
```

Make sure you are putting right Image Name and Package name in parameters.

As `getResources().getDrawable()` is being depreciated in API 22 , You can also try this

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```

You can implement the version check by using following code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

You should use the `getDrawable(int, Theme)` method for **API 21** instead of `getDrawable(int)`.Hence Calling the deprecated `getDrawable(int)` method is equivalent to calling `getDrawable(int, null)`.
 hope it will work for you .

Comment: i have activiti one and activity 2 when in activity 2 are some photo but will a small dimension when somebody click in a photo i want to change the background of the activity one this is what i want i have sent data with intent but sent image im 5 days working with this and i dont know do

Comment: If you want to set background of 1st activity from the image selection in 2nd activity , then you need to put the ID of that particular image In Intent Using     `Intent i = new Intent(SecondScreen.this, FirstScreen.class); i.putExtra("IMAGE_U_NEED", "IMAGE_ID"); startActivityForResult(i);` On First Activity you can get that Image by his ID through onActivityResult `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) `  This is in your First Activity , you pick Image id from data and set it to background

Comment: thank you so much but i have done ,i have solve the problem

Comment: Good , If my answer seems helpful for you , you can vote.