# Android - set an image using @android:drawable/AnImage programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I know how to use `@drawable` but how do I set `@android:drawable/ic_image` in code?

in XML, it would be

```
android:icon="@drawable/my_image"
```

or

```
android:icon="@mipmap/my_image"
```

and for android:drawable, it would be:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
```

but how to do the latest in code to set an image?

And which should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you out. Don't use getResource().getDrawable(). Its deprecated.

[Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

So basically:

```
 Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable);
    img.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

For android drawables you do:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

For Mipmaps:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.your_drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this code:

```
img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image, null));
```

Comment: @ArnoldB this getDrawable(id) is deprecated. but my suggestion is  getDrawable(id, theme). In my answer I send null as second parameter.

Comment: Yes. But still that does not make it correct. The way Google wants you to do it is the way I put in as an answer. That method will most likely get deprecated too as they have methods for themes with ResourcesCompat too. He asked for the correct way.

Comment: No problem. This has been very confusing for a while since Google keeps changing it. I don't even know why they don't have it down yet... really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

to use Android resources  you should use  "**android.R**" prefix like in resource name. this is code example:

```
    view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
```