# getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following some tutorials in android about how to create an app that can toggle the silent mode. Everything is fine until I got this errors:

[image]

```
The method getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated
```

Can you help me with this? I am new in Android. By the way I am using API 23 for this.

Comment: this is a Warning. don't worry . your application is running ?

Comment: I haven't check if it is running because I think that this is a big error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getResources().getDrawable()` is now deprecated.

You should use the following code from the support library instead:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
```

Using this method is equivalent to calling:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

As of API 21, you should use the `getDrawable(int, Theme)` method instead of `getDrawable(int`), as it allows you to fetch a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID for the given screen density/theme. Calling the deprecated `getDrawable(int)` method is equivalent to calling `getDrawable(int, null)`.

for more detail visit Here.

[Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried the first solution and I imported the missing classes and now the warning is gone. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning telling you that there is no support for this method by google and you shouldn't use it. You can use getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent,null); This null is for theme. If you have specific theme then you can provide theme here else null will suffice. 
Please accept if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**May be this image will solve your problem**

[image: this is Documentation given by Android itself]

Answer (score 1):

```
getDrawable(int) method was deprecated in API level 22.
```

Use **getDrawable(int, Theme)**