# Animate ImageView in dialog box

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

Iam trying to have an animation inside a `dialog` box so it would look like the animation is in front of the activity and be gone after 2 sec, but it always crash and only show the `layout`, not the animation, here are my codes:

### Method in my MainActivity.java

```
public void connectedAnim(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.connected);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    IVcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
    IVcon.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.connected);

    final AnimationDrawable animcon = (AnimationDrawable)IVcon.getDrawable();
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            animcon.start();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

### layout/connected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/IVcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### anim/connected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/connected" android:duration="500"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/disconnected" android:duration="500"/>

</animation-list>
```

### LogCat

> java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat
>   com.ardudroid.sample.bluetoothswitch.MainActivity$7.onShow(MainActivity.java:205)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1260)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> Line 205: `animcon.start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dialog.setContentView` instead of just `setContentView`

Move `anim/connected.xml` to `drawable/connected.xml` and leave it as it is.

Then in your connectedAnim(), instead of

```
IVcon = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
IVcon.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.connected);
```

use

```
IVcon = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
IVcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.connected);
```

and use this

```
AnimationDrawable animcon = (AnimationDrawable) IVcon.getBackground();
```

instead of

```
AnimationDrawable animcon = (AnimationDrawable)IVcon.getDrawable();
```

Comment: move it to the drawable folder? or put the codes of anim/connected to layout/connected?

Comment: just cut the `connected.xml` from `anim` directory and paste it to `drawable` directory.  
it is because we want to set a drawable as the background resource fro the `IVcon`

Comment: so the problem is i shouldnt set a background of anim cause .getDrawable() cant get it? and only drawables can be get by getBackground()?

Comment: you are right. Before, you weren't able to get the background using `getDrawable()` beacuse you were not setting one to `IVcon`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extends Dialog in your ImageView.so Change

```
  IVcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
```

into

```
  IVcon = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
```

and also

Read more details  [getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Comment: getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22 refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connected);
    ImageView IVcon = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.IVcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

[getDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29) is returning null.  You can only use it to get a drawable if you previously assigned a drawable to it. Unfortunately, you only assigned a *background* drawable, which is not the same thing.  Try using [getBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground()) instead.

I'm not sure you can simply call start() on a background drawable, though.

Comment: there's no getBackgroundDrawable() so i tried putting a background in the imageview, still gets an error

Comment: Sorry, just getBackground(). It returns a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

First move your **connected.xml** from **anim** to **drawable** folder.
other changes I have commented in side code.

```
public void connectedAnim(){
       Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connected); // change to dialog.setContentView
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            IVcon = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.IVcon);

            IVcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.connected);// Drawable file instead of anim move same file from anim folder to Drawable before use..

            final AnimationDrawable animcon = (AnimationDrawable) IVcon.getBackground(); // instead of getDrawable() use this
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    animcon.start();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: thank you! i already did this and it's working, you got the same answer as the other one at the top