# getDrawable(int id) is deprecated. How can I set an image?

Tags: android

Have a question! getDrawable() is deprecated in API 22. So, if I make an app with the min API 16, how can I set an image?

I saw that I can use  getDrawable(int id, theme) , but this was added in API 21, so I can't use it.

I've tried `setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.drawableName, null))` but this doesn't work either. Also with ContextCompat or getApplicationContext() it doesn't work.

```
private ImageView weatherIcon;
weatherIcon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);
if(weatherReportList.size()>0){
            DailyWeatherReport report=weatherReportList.get(0);
            switch (report.getWeather()){
                case DailyWeatherReport.WEATHER_TYPE_CLOUDS:
                    weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.cloudy, null));
                    weatherIconMini.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.cloudy, null));
                case DailyWeatherReport.WEATHER_TYPE_RAIN:
                    weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.rainy));
                    weatherIconMini.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.rainy, null));

                default:
                    weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.sunny, null));
                    weatherIconMini.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.sunny, null));


            }
```

This is not a duplicate of that post. I've tried all the methods from there but none on them worked.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29041466/3626214

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Comment: Though the `getDrawable()` is deprecated, but it could still work right now, so maybe something wrong in your code somewhere else

Answer (score 7):

you can use

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, /*your drawable like R.drawable.drawableName*/));
```

Comment: And I get the context by getContext?

Comment: yes you can and you can also use `getActivity()` if it is fragment or `yourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()` if activity.

Comment: But this doesn't work either. :( Maybe I have a problem with my code, but I don't think so.

Comment: `weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.rainy));`

Comment: If this code is inside an activity I would always suggest to give "this" as context.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way,

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
} else {
    return context.getResources().getDrawable(resource, null);
}
```

may helps you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my project has a bug, but I can't identify it. If I try on other projects, it works with any of the answers above.