# Tab icons disappeared in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have defined three different class to handle tab icons.The following is `BaseActivity` class.

```
public class MainScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabBarView.IconTabProvider {

private int[] tab_icons =
        {R.drawable.launcher_inactive,
                R.drawable.chat_inactive,
                R.drawable.t3_inactive,
                R.drawable.launcher,
                R.drawable.chat_active,
                R.drawable.t3_active
         };
```

Then in `TabView.java` I defined setIcon as follow

```
public void setIcon(int resId) {
    setIcon(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(resId));
 }
```

Since`getDrawable` is deprecated, I think this is the only problem I cannot see tab icons

```
public class TabView extends LinearLayout {

private ImageView mImageView;
private TextView mTextView;

public TabView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.actionBarTabStyle);
}

public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarTabTextStyle, outValue, true);

    int txtstyle = outValue.data;

    int pad = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());

    mImageView = new ImageView(context);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));//hadi andaze icon taba
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    mTextView = new TextView(context);
    mTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // mTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(pad);
    mTextView.setTextAppearance(context, txtstyle);
    ;

    this.addView(mImageView);
    // this.addView(mTextView);

    this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(determineScreenDensity(), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

public void setIcon(int resId) {
    Log.i("Case+","" +resId);
    setIcon(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(resId));

}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    if (icon != null) {
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    } else {
        mImageView.setImageResource(View.GONE);
        Log.i("icon","null" +null);
    }
}

public void setText(int resId, int ico) {
    setText(getContext().getString(resId), ico);
}

public void setText(CharSequence text, int ico) {
    mTextView.setText(text);
    mTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ico, 0, 0, 0);
    ;
}
```

then from `TabBarView.java` class I called `setIcon()`

```
 public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    mSelectedTab = position;
    mOffset = positionOffset;

    invalidate();

    if (delegatePageListener != null) {
        delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }

    if (position == 0) {

        tabView1.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(3));
        tabView1.setScaleX(1);
        tabView1.setScaleY(1);


        tabView2.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(1));
      //  tabView2.setScaleX(2);
      //  tabView2.setScaleY(2);


        tabView3.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(2));
        tabView3.setScaleX(1.1f);
        tabView3.setScaleY(1.1f);

    } else if (position == 1) {
        tabView1.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(0));
        tabView1.setScaleX(0.7f);
        tabView1.setScaleY(0.7f);

       // tabView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_button_2);

        tabView2.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(4));
        //tabView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_round_button);
        //tabView2.setScaleX(2);
        //tabView2.setScaleY(2);


        tabView3.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(2));
        tabView3.setScaleX(1.1f);
        tabView3.setScaleY(1.1f);
       // tabView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_button_2);

    } else if (position == 2) {
        tabView1.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(0));

        //tabView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_button_2);
        tabView2.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(1));

        //tabView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_button_2);
        tabView3.setIcon(((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(5));
      //  tabView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_round_button);

       tabView3.setScaleX(1.7f);
       tabView3.setScaleY(1.7f);
    /*
       LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.setMargins(40,0,0,0);
        tabView1.setLayoutParams(params);
        tabView2.setLayoutParams(params);
        tabView3.setLayoutParams(params);
     // tabView2.setPadding(20,0,20,0);

       //tabView3.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
        */

         }
      }
```

the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22) cannot be applied to my code. I appreciate if you can help me with this case.

Comment: Where from and how are you calling `setIcon(int)` method?

Comment: @azizbekian I defined `setIcon(int)`  in TabView Class. this class is provided above

Comment: The question was where from are you calling `setIcon()` and not where is `setIcon()` declared.

Comment: @azizbekian sry. I called `setIcon` from TabBarView. java class. I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> This work in my case

```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, context.getTheme()));
                } else {
                    holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
                }
```

> // as per you requirement

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, context.getTheme()));
                } else {
                    setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
                }
```

Comment: your solution cannot be applied to my structure. please read my explanations

Comment: Which explanations?

Comment: @kalabalik `setIcon` is defined in a different class and I call it from another class. also `R.drawable.name` is declared in MainScreenPager.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TabView` code looks pretty straight forward. Only alternative I can think of is you can try calling `invalidate()` inside the `setIcon()` after setting the drawable as is will try to redraw the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working below API level 23 then i think you have issue in using getDrawable we have some options which can be used in place of `getContext().getResources().getDrawable()`

It can be used with `ContextCompat`

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.drawble_name);
```

Please try this as getDrawable with resources is deprecated above API level 22.

Comment: due to the structure of my code, I cannot use it and this is the exact problem