# Reference a drawable

Tags: java, android

I am trying to cast a drawable in my code but I get this error

> An instance of type android.view.View' can not be of type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

**Here is my code:**

```
mydrawable = (Drawable) findViewById(R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

Comment: findViewById it means this is a View. It can't be casted as Drawable.

Comment: Because this not the way to get a drawable, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/5914654)

Comment: Refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/3974530

Answer (score 0):

Return type of `findViewById()` is a `View` which cannot be casted to Drawable.

**Replace**

```
(Drawable) findViewById(R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

**with**

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast this `View` as `Drawable`. You can cast this as `EditText`, `TextView` because those finally extend the class `View`. But `Drawable` doesn't extend `View`.

**Try this**

```
mydrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.mydrawable, null);
```

This will be type of `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` and your problem may be solved.

Comment: @cricket_007 did you mean `getBaseContext()` ?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, getting resources was right https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay than .