# How to set imageview resource from variable?

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of images (hundreds) and I need to put some of them as a resource of `ImageView`, but if I would create If Then set Image to Image name, I die from these tons of code. I want to set Image resource which name is inside a variable, but I can't find out how. If I have 
`img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);`
How can I assign variable name at `my_image` instead of true image name?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 String resourceName = "clouds";
 int resourceIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getPackageName());
```

Then

```
imgView.setImageResource(resourceIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I clearly understood your request but why don't you try to do that instead :

```
    int my_image = R.id.my_image;
    img.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, my_image));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/8526518 for more informations about ContextCompat

Answer (score 0):

if you can prefer assets folder rather than resource,
then you can try this code

create sub-folder in assets directory. use getAssets().list() for getting all file names from assets:

```
String[] images =getAssets().list("images");
ArrayList<String> listImages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(images));
```

Now to set image in imageview you first need to get bitmap using image name from assets :

```
InputStream inputstream=mContext.getAssets().open("images/"
                                      +listImages.get(position));
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputstream, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

just a convenient refactoring of the S-Sh answer if you use kotlin and like using its extensions functions:

```
fun ImageView.loadDrawableFromName(name:String, ctx: Context, visible:Int=View.VISIBLE){
    val resId = ctx.resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", ctx.packageName)
    this.setImageResource(resId)
    this.visibility = visible
}
```

you can call it in both ways:

```
imgname="IMGNAME"
myimageview.loadDrawableFromName(imgname, ctx)
```

and

```
imgname="IMGNAME"
myimageview.loadDrawableFromName("@drawable/$imgname", ctx)
```